# How to update a component inside of dataTable from outside of it

Tags: jsf, datatable, components, primefaces

I am using Mojarra implementation of JSF 2.1 with Primefaces 3.2.

My problem approximately looks like this:

```
<p:dialog id="someDialog">
  ..
  <h:form id="dialogForm">        
    <p:commandLink action=".."update=":someForm:someUIRepeat:someDataTable:someInputTextArea"/> 
  </h:form>
</p:dialog>


<h:form id="someForm">
  <ui:repeat id="someUIRepeat" value=".." ..>
    <p:dataTable id="someDataTable" value=.. >

      <p:column>
        <p:inputTextarea id="someInputTextarea" value=../>
      <p:column>

     .. here go other columns
  <ui:repeat>
</h:form>
```

The issue is that when I click on the commandLink in the dialog the inputTextarea is not updated. However, if I write this in the update of the commandLink:
  update=":someForm:someUIRepeat:someDataTable,:someForm:someUIRepeat:someDataTable:someInputTextArea"

then the whole dataTable gets updated and the inputTextarea updates as well, but the values in the fields located in other columns get erased after I click on the commandLink in the dialog.

The reason why I put dataTable inside of ui:repeat is that I need to bind a dataTable with each row of one collection and I think it's not related to my problem.

Any ideas how I can solve this problem?

Thanks in advance,

Nurzhan.

Comment: try adding process="someForm:someUIRepeat:someDataTable" and setting update=":someForm:someUIRepeat:someDataTable" , this should not clear the data of the table and update the table...

Comment: @Daniel Thanks for your reply. I tried your solution but it didn't work me. When I added process=".." to commandLink, it didn't update anything, even the whole dataTable.

Comment: sorry my bad... its cause the <p:commandLink is not in the "someForm" form

Comment: @Daniel So, what should I do? ))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for start try this

added `onclick="jQuery('#someForm:someButton').click();"`(check the exact id of your hidden button) to your `<p:commandLink` inside the dialog

set the `update` to `update=":someForm:someUIRepeat:someDataTable"`

and add

```
<h:commandButton id="someButton" style="display:none">
    <f:ajax execute="@form"></f:ajax>
</h:commandButton>
```

to `<h:form id="someForm">`

explanation: the purpose of the hidden button is to execute (send its values) the form to the server so that when you do call `update` the fields wont be erased...

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I couldn't fix my problem, although I did everything as you said.

Comment: add onclick="alert('a')" to the "someButton" to see that the jquery .click() realy doing its job - cause migth be that the selector is wrong and cant find the someButton button